# Calling executable from nodejs app on Heroku results in "Permission Denied" but running from bash is ok. Why?

Tags: node.js, bash, heroku

We have a nodejs app on Heroku. Somewhere in the code we run this

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('/bin/bash', ['-c', '/app/node_modules/wkhtmltopdf-prebuilt/bin/linux64/bin/wkhtmltopdf' + ' | cat ; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}']);
```

But if we do so, we get `Permission denied`, even when the executable is chmod 0777. If I run the wkhtmltopdf command from the Heroku bash, it works just fine. Just when we run it from within node, we get `Permission Denied`.

Moreover, if we simply `fs.readFileSync()` or even `fs.unlinkSync()` from within node, we don't encounter any issues. The file can be read, written to, removed etc.

Does anybody have a pointer?

Comment: have you tried to open the file for reading within the node? see if it's execution problem or mere read issue? and what's the first line of your script (the shebang) ?

Comment: are you running bash and nodejs as the same user? It is possible that the user that nodejs is running as doesn't have the privileges to read/execute that file.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre opening, writing, deleting the file is no problem. I've updated the answer, also with the literal code that we use. That would probably generate a shebang like instruction under water?

Comment: @euphoria83 we run the '/bin/bash' command from the node REPL, which in turn is started from the bash, so I would assume they all have the same privileges. Regardless, the file has 0777 so anybody can do anything to the file...

Comment: your app is a binary file, no need to run it using `bash`, and piping to `cat`. I would simplify as follows: `var child = spawn('/app/node_modules/wkhtmltopdf-prebuilt/bin/linux64/bin/wkhtmltopdf');` (plus I suspect that putting `|` in the arguments is a problem)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks. We are depending on an external lib that calls the code like that... So I'm afraid I can't change that. But I found the issue... See my answer. It's stupid, really :-(

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue. It's quite stupid, actually. We were doing the `chmod` from a `heroku run bash` which I *thought* would run a bash on the actual running web dyno.

However, it turns out that running `heroku run bash` will spin up a one-off dyno with a copy of the file-system etc. So when I did chmod and checked if node could read, delete etc, then I indeed could, but that was *on the one-off system*, not on the running web dyno.

While chmodding on the one-off dyno, nothing actually changed on the web dyno, so the same Permission Denied error kept coming up.